# summary stats on rows of dataframe?

Tags: r, count, dataframe, rows, summary

I have some count data as seen below. If I run `summary(x)`, this gives me column data.

```
x
line_796 line_799 line_801 line_812  line_884 line_892 line_908 
    0        0         -        0        0        0        2
    0        -         0        0        0        2        0
    0        0         0        0        0        2        0

summary(x)
line_796 line_799 line_801 line_812 line_884 line_892 line_908 
   -:0     -:1       -:1       -:0      -:0      -:0      -:0
   0:3     0:2       0:2       0:3      0:3      0:1      0:2
   2:0     2:0       2:0       2:0      2:0      2:2      2:1
```

How would I do this for rows to get the output below?

```
 1 -:1, 0: 5, 2:1
 2 -:1, 0: 5, 2:1
 3 -:0, 0: 6, 2:1
```

Comment: `summary(t(dat))` might work

Comment: @LegalizeIt  That works, add as an answer

Comment: thanks everyone that worked, handy trick